# What is the equivalent of App.Path and App.EXEName in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need some help to find the equivalent of App.Path and App.EXEName in VB.Net in a DLL.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to MSDN ([App Object Changes in Visual Basic .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984469(v=vs.71).aspx)), the replacement for both is

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

It contains the full path (`App.Path`) as well as the file name (`App.EXEName`). You can split the information using the helper methods from the `Path` class:

```
' Import System.Reflection and System.IO at the top of your class file
Dim location = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
Dim appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(location)       ' C:\Some\Directory
Dim appName = Path.GetFileName(location)            ' MyLibrary.DLL
```

---

**UPDATE** (thanks to the commenters): If you are executing this code in a DLL and you want the name of the EXE that called the DLL, you need to use [`GetEntryAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx) instead of `GetExecutingAssembly`. Note that `GetEntryAssembly` might return `Nothing` if your DLL was called from an unmanaged EXE.

Comment: You didn't get that right, he wants the EXE path, not the DLL path.  Use Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() instead.

Comment: I'm working with a DLL I think I need Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by,

```
Application.ExecutablePath
```

It contains both directory and executable file, to separate it, you can use `System.IO.Path` class

```
Dim ExePath = Application.ExecutablePath
Dim ExeFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(ExePath)  ' which is App.Path in VB6
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath & "\test.txt")
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    Dim firstLine = lines(0)
    Dim fields = firstLine.Split(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(44))
    '  TextBox1.Text = ExeFolder
    'Id = fields(4)
    TextBox2.Text = fields(0)
End Sub
```

Comment: To make your answer useful and to avoid getting downvoted please explain how your code sample adresses the question.